# Ionic Framework (Angularjs) $localStorage not removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, local-storage

why is it that the `$localStorage.mydata` is not removed when using `$localStorage.removeItem('mydata')` ? `$localStorage.mydata` is still present even I already fired up this function.

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
$scope.logout = function()
{
    $localStorage.removeItem('mydata');

    alert('Success!');
};
});
```

Comment: You're definitely getting the success alert, right? If so, how are you validating that $localStorage.mydata is present? I think if you remove it, the value will be defined but it will be null. Also what are your results if you use $localStorage.getItem rather than just accessing it as a property?

Comment: I use ` if($localStorage.hasOwnProperty("accessToken") === true)`

Comment: Is $localStorage part of Ionic or are you using something like ngStorage? I wrote a fiddle to test basic window.localStorage operations and there doesn't seem to be an issue. I'm sure Ionic supports native window.localStorage so that makes me wonder if there is a bug with whatever is providing $localStorage to you. Here's a link to the fiddle in case you're interested: http://jsfiddle.net/jjgasax5/

Comment: I'm using ngStorage. I already search couple times on how to delete it. All of them suggests to use .removeItem(); but it doesn't work that for me. Instead I use `delete $localStorage.mydata` and it works.

Comment: If you replace your calls on $localStorage with window.localStorage do your results change? I think ngStorage basically maps them 1:1 but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's basically a typing error. It must be $localstorage. But I can confirm that the removeItem function is not available.